# Unable to edit posts with pending edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

It's currently not possible to edit posts where a suggested edit is pending; even if I've already placed an accept/reject vote, I just get a popup box when I click on 'edit' to approve or reject the edit. Normally this wouldn't be much of a problem, as the suggested edit could be approved or rejected - however, when the suggested edits system is turned off (as it is now) this results in posts being completely un-editable - e.g. [Within resources in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905888/within-resources-in-jar)

The suggested edits system should auto-reject all pending edits when it is disabled.

Comment: It is not disabled. We just supress the menu notification till 5 are pending

Comment: Ah, interesting. In any case, though, low-rep users shouldn't be able to block edits by high-rep users by placing a suggested edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been possible for quite a while.

If you would like to edit a post that has a pending edit, you can click the `improve` button. This will automatically accept the edit and let you continue from there.

We are seeing about 80 or so posts a day, being "improved". That is, the edit suggestion did not go far enough. On the other hand approx 650 suggested edits are approved a day.

<sub>numbers subject to change as the system gets more popular</sub>

Comment: I've used it, and I love it.  This was a source of frustration for me and the improve option is a great solution.

Answer (score 16):

I don't really believe that this is a solution to the problem, because the Improve button will only work *if* I wanted to accept the pending edit. If I wanted to reject it and then work from there, this doesn't really work out.

Comment: I want to be able to look at the original markdown just to see whether the edit was correct or not. I can't do that.