# Editing questions does not need a second opinion, but approving an edit does

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits)

I've come across what seems to be a strange behavior of stackoverflow:

- I have the privilege to edit other user's questions. When I do so, it does not need to be approved and other people see the edited question.
- When an edit of a question needs to be approved (I guess because the editor does not have sufficient reputation), I can approve that edit. Still the edit needs to be approved by a second user. Until then, people see the original version of the question.

What is the reason behind this? In my opinion, someone who may edit a question without the need for approval should be able to approve an edit such that no second approval is necessary.

Comment: may be to prevent accidental clicking?

Comment: The approving an edit will also add reputation to the editor.

Comment: For a dedicated user, _approving_ a bad edit is a lot easier than performing it.