# Why can't a 2000+ user immediately approve an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits)

I think that if I'm allowed to edit a post, I should be allowed to approve someone else's edits immediately (i.e., without waiting for others to also approve it).

Currently, if I've voted approve on some edit, I can't even edit the post myself. It just says

> *You have voted to approve this edit - awaiting more votes.*

What I do now-days is that, instead of approving someone else's edit, I ignore their edit and perform the edit myself directly instead. This can't be the intention of this feature?

<sup>Feels like this probably has been discussed elsewhere but I couldn't find it. Feel free to close as dup if this is the case.</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits), [Why do edits need two approvals, even from high rep users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85846/why-do-edits-need-two-approvals-even-from-high-rep-users), [Editing questions does not need a second opinion, but approving an edit does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84727/editing-questions-does-not-need-a-second-opinion-but-approving-an-edit-does)

Comment: Aha. there it was. voting to close. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, I almost always find myself clicking "Improve" to make further changes, as *none* of the suggested edits that I see go far enough in making the necessary changes. I hardly ever hit "Accept", although I do hit "Reject" a fair amount. Hard to say whether or not this is the "intention" of the feature.

Comment: Aha, I see. I'll keep that in mind.