# Remove 2 vote requirement to approve suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

What is the reasoning for the 2 vote requirement to approve a suggested edit?  If a 2000+ rep user has the ability to edit on their own, then why do they need to vote to approve a suggested edit?

I propose removing the 2 vote requirement for 2000+ rep users as those users have the ability to edit on their own without a vote.

Comment: I would vote to approve far fewer edits if I didn't have to get agreement from anyone.

Comment: A better "original" question for this is: [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78799/148310).

Comment: And for future reference: this [only applies to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284).