# Are the Stack Overflow edit queue and flag queue becoming slower due to technical issues or growth?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review, moderation, flag-queue

Is SO suffering a performance loss from the network / hosting infrastructure, or is there an unexpected audience these days ?

- I have noticed for several days that the edit suggestions approval take much more time that formerly.
- Like for the moderation flags (some of mine are unreviewed for more than a week).
- Two days ago, I started to get "The edit queue is full" message (never seen before during the last year) so from time to time I cannot submit some modifications while the question is already changed.

Are you informed of such problems?

Comment: I am assuming you are simply asking about the edit queue being full, otherwise, where exactly are you getting your information about "performance loss" and "unexpected audience" (whatever _that_ means). Can you confirm/deny/expand?

Comment: Yeah, title/lead don't really seem to match the body of the question. But the edit queue is a problem for SO

Comment: Well, RE: Flags SO could really use more moderators, there's no two ways about that one. Edits need a better system for handling by normal users. These aren't "performance" issues in the hardware sense, SO is still pretty blazing fast in that regard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven't noticed any *performance* problems with Stack Overflow, but there are a couple of different forces at play causing a slowdown in moderation lately.

- First, several of the normally active diamond moderators on Stack Overflow have been very busy with their regular jobs for the past few weeks.  This has caused the moderator queue to get more backed up than normal.
- Second, a lot of people are participating in [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/1288) that's been going on for nearly two months.  That's what keeps filling up the suggested edit queue.  **If you can approve/reject edits, please consider pitching in.  Thanks.  :)**

The Community team is aware of both of these issues and is working on solutions.  (Suggestions welcome.)

Comment: Does the edit approval/rejection right comes with the Strunk&White badge (80 edits)? I need 14 more edits to get it (including 2 waiting for approval) :)

Comment: No, it comes with the right to edit posts directly (2k reputation), although at that point you can't see the edit queue, and can only find suggested edits if there is one on a question you are looking at. At 5k reputation, the edit queue becomes available via the /review page

Comment: does improve count as a vote? :) or can I clear the edit queue by "improving" each suggested edit

Comment: @örs Yes, improving a suggested edit does take it out of the queue (because at that point it's handled).

Comment: Is there a good reason two approve votes are required from users who could have just made the edit in question themselves?

Comment: @BenBrocka I guess we were getting a lot of bad approvals at one point.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78806/1288

Comment: @örs `improve` makes Community cast the vote, so after you've used your 50, you can still hit improve - at least, it worked that way when I tried a couple of weeks ago, haven't tested lately.