# Approving via edit link within question should behave differently than via queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, 10k-tools

It's always (well, for a long time) annoyed me that, as a 10K user, I can very easily edit a post and have it apply immediately. Whereas if a lower-rep user has already suggested an edit, whether I agree or disagree with their edit, **I can't approve or reject it without at least one other person approving**. Which seems relatively silly when you think about it, and can **significantly slow down the process of improving a post**.

I understand the reason for this behavior: people plow through the edit queue and maybe have less investment in truthfully reviewing the edit and ensuring that it makes sense, especially without having any direct experience with the question in context (and perhaps rushing to get some badge makes this process even more careless). But I think this type of mindless edit is far less likely to happen if **I am reviewing the edit because I was actually on the question** and clicked the `edit (0)` link, rather than because I was simply plowing through the queue.

I am not sure of the technical difficulty to implement what I'm asking for, and I suspect you'll down-vote me into oblivion and/or close this as a duplicate of [Why do we need multiple approvers for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits). But since this triple-stamp process can occasionally **really slow down clarifying or improving a post**, I still feel justified in asking:

Can we waive the requirement to have another set of eyes approve an approval (or approve a rejection) when and only when (a) **the approver is a 10K user** and (b) the approver files his/her vote to approve or reject the edit **from within the question** vs. from within the edit queue?

Comment: I support this, it annoys me as well.

Comment: Can you click "improve" (without really changing anything) and submit the edit that way in order to bypass this?  Obviously, leaving the "This edit was helpful" checkbox checked so the original suggester gets credit.

Comment: @jadarnel27 seems like extra steps that shouldn't be necessary for 10K users. Usually my goal is to make further edits *after* the original editor and I'd generally prefer to keep those separate.

Comment: +1. I can see the need for multiple eyes in the queue, but approving an edit on the question does seem like it should make it take effect.

Comment: If you're going to perform further edits, using the "improve" button actually does approve the suggested edit immediately (and creates two separate revisions).  But I do agree with your proposal in general, +1 from me as well.

Comment: @jadarnel27 well, I might not always be ready to perform further edits right then and there. And I'm not *always* doing so anyway - often the suggested edit is handling the same issue I was going to fix.

Comment: You might be able to improve it - but you have to work off the changed data not the original

Comment: @Mark that's a good point. Also, sometimes the suggested edit is *not* helpful and I want to reject it and improve the post in my own way. If I can only vote to reject it and have to wait for someone else to agree with me, the chances I'm going to come back and revisit hours later after having my edit stifled when I was ready to implement it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Take a look at [Waffles' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109769/148672) to [Do we need a 'reject and improve' button?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I get it now, thanks. Still that's not the only scenario where my suggestion would apply.

Comment: Keep in mind that if this was implemented you will have people, in the edit queue, clicking the link to the question and going there to approve/reject it so that they don't need a second vote.  Because of that this suggestion really is very little more than removing the two vote requirement entirely.

Comment: @Servy note that my requirement also dictates that only 10K users can bypass the multi-stamp check. Could some 10K users abuse this? Possibly. But nobody else could.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So then your suggestion is effectively equivalent to saying that 10k users should get 2 votes when reviewing edits.  If you're going to change it in on place just do it in both; it won't stop anyone anyway.

Comment: @Servy I'm saying that a 10K user should be able to approve an edit with the same minimal roadblocks that exist for them to edit it themselves. The extra steps of having to leave the edit queue and go to the question should mitigate any potential abuse and should in fact make it more likely that they'll pay attention to the entire question in full context instead of just in the context of the edit. I'm not sure why this is a bad thing. What I'm trying to do is to make it easier for us to approve edits in the process of viewing, reviewing and dealing with questions, not open doors for abuse.

Comment: @Servy why do you seem to think 10K users would use this to sneak edits in that otherwise might get rejected? What would a 10K user gain from that? After all if they really want to make a change to the question they can do so after the approval anyway, or they could "improve" the question as otherwise suggested here. So I'm not sure where this abuse would come from.

Comment: @AaronBertrand First off, a 2k user can edit a post without it needing to be approved, not just a 10k user.  Anyone that can approve someone else's edit can, by definition, edit a post without approval on their own (if it doesn't already have pending edits).  If one is worried about a person making the incorrect decision on the approval of an edit in the queue, they should be able to make that same incorrect decision in the question itself, at least a fair amount of the time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not saying that 10k users would abuse this change.  What I said is that if you remove a roadblock in one place you may as well remove it everywhere.  You logical arguments also apply equally to 2k users as they do to 10k users.  Not I've never said that I disagree with the suggestion, I'm merely stating that it is, in practice, the same as removing the roadblock entirely.  You're the one inferring that it's a bad thing, and that this suggestion is a significant improvement.  Either both suggestions are good, or neither are, in my mind.

Comment: @Servy what I'm suggesting is that a 10K user should be able to make a judgment call on a <2K user's suggested edit, without requiring approval from another 2K user. The reason against this has been queue-plowing, which is why my suggestion involved only functionality from within a question. Making the user go to the question effectively thwarts queue-plowing, and while you're right that is just a couple of extra steps, I don't see it as a major source of abuse.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If someone is going to abuse it from the queue, they'll abuse it in the question.  If they can be trusted not to abuse it in the question, they can be trusted not to abuse it in the queue.  In my eyes the assertion that a 10k user will abuse the system in the queue, but not in the question, is incorrect.

Comment: @Servy by "abuse" I mean mindless approvals, not intentional approvals. Queue-plowing can lead to mindless approvals, which require at least one other approval (mindless or not). If I have to go to the question in order to approve an edit "in one less step", I'm not likely to be committed to put in the work to apply that edit without waiting for a second approval. I'm also at least slightly more likely to actually read the question and make a more informed decision about the edit. I'm only highlighting a difference because "remove 2 approvals" has been rejected specifically for queue-plowing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Your assumption that they're more likely to read the question in more depth and make a significantly more informed decision, just because they performed a second click to get to the actual question, is false in my eyes and needs to be supported at the very least.

Comment: @Servy what evidence could I possibly present unless the feature were implemented and every single user behaved in the exact same way? Give me a break. I'm only stating what is potentially likely to happen if there are multiple steps to the process. I didn't say people would do it, I said "slightly more likely."