# Suggested edits should not lock the ability for others to edit

Tags: discussion, status-completed, suggested-edits

I found a suggested edit that was OK but not that great, I wanted to fix the question myself since it was a quick and easy thing to do. But I could not do that. If I click edit, it brings up the suggested edit window and tells me to vote on it. I tried to reject it but then it just brings it up again.

This is a real annoyance since a bad suggested edit will delay the editing of a question, so the question will be in a bad state for longer, and this will hurt the asker even more.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78328/edit-approve-review-rant-closed (closed) :)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that was a rant, not an objective problem/complaint/discussion.

Comment: It was closed for having nothing constructive to add to the issue. Just a rant. I on the other hand don't use the word sucks in every other word and bring up why this is a bad thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits)

Comment: Thanks @Yi for the link. I'm downvoting jeff on that one.

Comment: Downvoted also.

Comment: I will laugh if he gets downvoted enough to trigger a delete.

Comment: See also [Is everyone in favor of the new "Everyone can edit" idea?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581)

Comment: And also  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79149/why-were-edit-suggestions-designed-to-sometimes-hinder-the-communitys-ability-to

Answer (score 7):

The question is, how do you handle the event in the event the suggested edit is accepted after you complete your edit?

It'd be smarter IMO, to permit people who have the ability to perform edits themselves, to veto the edit completely, or perhaps, take responsibility for the edit by "adopting" the change as a basis for a new edit.

Comment: Aye, something like that might work.

Comment: I was going to suggest this - an option to edit a suggested edit would allow you to improve half-edits, and both could appear sequentially in the revision history as normal.