# Approval voting blocks edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits)
>   [Suggested edits should not lock the ability for others to edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79365/suggested-edits-should-not-lock-the-ability-for-others-to-edit)

This question has some minor formatting errors, and could perhaps do with the "homework" tag being added:

- [Lisp Insert Sorting Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739608/lisp-insert-sorting-problem)

So I attempted to edit it, but instead of getting the edit window, I got an edit approval popup showing me that another editor has proposed a similar change to the one I was going to make. So I approved the edit. But the approval didn't go through: it needs more than one vote.

So if there had been *no* proposed edit, I could just have edited the question and fixed the problem. But because another editor has proposed an edit, I cannot now make this change. In effect, the proposed edit blocks all edits until the approval has gone through or not. It would be nice if this didn't happen.

Similar points have been made by other users:

- [Instant edit approval for high-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94581/instant-edit-approval-for-high-rep-users)
- [Instant approval of revisions for users with edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85758/instant-approval-of-revisions-for-users-with-edit-privileges)

More were noted by Cody Gray and Popular Demand in comments:

- [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits)
- [Why were edit suggestions designed to sometimes hinder the community's ability to edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79149/why-were-edit-suggestions-designed-to-sometimes-hinder-the-communitys-ability-to)
- [Why do we need multiple approvers for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits)
- [Suggested edits should not lock the ability for others to edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79365/suggested-edits-should-not-lock-the-ability-for-others-to-edit)
- [Is everyone in favor of the new "everyone can edit" idea? Is this really such a good idea?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581/is-everyone-in-favor-of-the-new-everyone-can-edit-idea-is-this-really-such-a-g)
- [Suggested edits should not lock the ability for others to edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79365/suggested-edits-should-not-lock-the-ability-for-others-to-edit)

I think the number of times this has been reported is evidence that the interface is not well designed for new users. A user in my situation is focused on the task of *Editing the question/answer* but what the suggested edit interface offers is the facility to *Improve the suggestion*. These are not the same thing at all.

Comment: You can always click "Improve". There was a ["Reject and Improve"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button) proposal, but I guess that wouldn't work because we need two users to reject an edit as well, so it would still sit in queue.

Comment: I totally missed the option to do that! So consider my feature request to be to improve the approval interface.

Comment: @Gareth Improve it how?

Comment: Hmmm, good question. The edit in question has been approved now, so I can't go back and look at the panel to see why I missed this feature. Where should I look to see an example?

Comment: @Gareth It looks like [this](http://so.mrozekma.com/suggested-edit-dialog.png) (actually, now that you're 10k you can just go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/), [Why were edit suggestions designed to sometimes hinder the community's ability to edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79149), [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799), [Suggested edits should not lock the ability for others to edit.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79365), [Is everyone in favor of the new “everyone can edit” idea? Is this really such a good idea?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581)

Comment: @Michael: I guess I saw the "Improve" button but didn't understand what it meant. I didn't want to Improve the suggested edit; I wanted to Edit the question.

Comment: @Cody: Those duplicates suggest that this is a general difficulty with this dialog.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I for one **hate it**. I have full edit privileges; if I want to make an edit, I should be able to do that. I especially hate having to wait for someone else's poor, half-assed edit to be approved/rejected by at least 1 more user before I can fix the glaring problems with the post. I've taken to *only* using the "Improve" button 90% of the time, which I don't really feel is appropriate, since knowing it is actually the "Approve & Improve" button, and I don't think these people deserve any rep points for their less-than-tepid edits. No traction on fixing it so far, though.