# Please allow tag editing when question is waiting for pending edit votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

Note that this is not the same as: [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits)

Mistagged questions should be retaggable immediately.

Comment: is my answer enough for a status-completed here?

Comment: @waffles: Sure  :)  I hope, yet to be tested. Now to find such a case.

Comment: Here's such a case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287434/c-gui-development-bitmap-vs-vector-graphics-cpu-consumption (needs `juce` and `performance` tags, not `cpu-usage`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I just *fixed* this and a slew of similar requests.

If you would like to edit a post that has a pending edit and can't wait, you can click the <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> button:

> [image]

This button allows you to "edit the edit", add tags and whatnot.

At the end of the process when you submit the edit, the Community user will accept the suggested edit AND your edit will be applied:

> [image]

We still disable the quick-retag menu, but offer you a way around the issue if you are in a rush.

Comment: Ah YES I like that.  There have been many times where I saw and accepted a pending edit only so I could have a chance at editing it myself more completely.  Sometimes being turned away since I am the first to accept.

Comment: @waffles: problem is, once you vote to approve the edit, the "Improve" function is no longer available.

Comment: @Ben so what you suggest? If you have a concrete suggestion, a new feature request can be a good idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the rep to  change the tags without a pending edit do it.

If you can't then well wait until the post is edit and then fix it.

Comment: I got over 30k rep on SO. I approved the edit, but it was still waiting for more votes.

Comment: @leppie is there any other edits waiting. What question is that I will make a small edit then see what happens when you aorove it.

Comment: It has been retagged now, but this was the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075889/extract-a-part-of-string-using-a-pattern-start-with-a-value-of-varibale-in-perl Needed a `perl` tag.

Comment: @leppie the tag was added before my asnwer

Comment: @leppie: I did the same thing, approved an edit, then wanted to fix the tags.  Still not possible.