# Do "Improved" suggested edits count toward the proofreader and reviewer badges?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, badges

After clicking "Improve" on a suggested edit and making additional modifications, the suggested edit gets [approved by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community) instead of the user who Improved the post.

Do these edits count toward the [proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader) and [reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) badges?

From my observations, it seems like they do not.

Comment: Well, it does presumably count toward [copy editor](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor), so I'm not sure it needs to count toward even more badges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until now, "Improve" did not count toward the count of actions that trigger the Proofreader badge.

But given [we've now replaced "Improve" with actions that explicitly reject or approve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) edits, it seems fair to make these edits count toward the badge as well - after all, they *are* approve/reject reviews, they just happen to include an edit as well!

Geoff has made the change - after the next build, a few enthusiastic editors will be getting a new badge.

Comment: worth noting that approvals and rejections through "Improve" are currently [attributed to Community user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238793/165773), and reviewer stats for approvals / rejections aren't displayed

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why I got that badge today. My last rejection or approval of a proposed edit was two weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

When you improve a suggested edit, it gets approved by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community); you result as user that edited the post. As consequence of this, that post doesn't result between your reviews, and it doesn't count to get the badge.

For example, I improved a suggested edit for [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212612/225647) on [OCJP - to implement printf in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212049/ocjp-to-implement-printf-in-java) (February 9); the revision page for that answer shows the following:

[image: screenshot]

The ["reviews" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno?tab=activity) doesn't show it as one my reviews, but it is shown for the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=24).

[image: screenshot]

If you then click on the "suggested" link shown in the revisions page for that answer, you will notice that Community user is reported to be the approver, not me.

[image: screenshot]

Improved edits are not counted as reviews; that is what I have experienced in the Stack Exchange sites where I am active.

Comment: This matches my observations. Now, for the *"Should they?"* part... :P

Comment: Perhaps I should move that into a separate question.

Comment: I think they should, especially on Stack Overflow where two users needs to approve or reject a suggested edit. If improving a suggested edit would be counted, it would be like a work-around to the "two users needs to approve an edit" rule.

Comment: Yeah, the whole two-vote system feels weird to me in general.

Comment: I meant, they should not count as approved edits.

Comment: Update: [Improving edits now counts as a review.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155496)

Answer (score 1):

I ran a little experiment:

1. Opened up one of my [recently actioned suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/198292) and observed my approve/reject count:

   > Rob Hruska approved 222 edit suggestions, and rejected 96 edit suggestions.
2. Made the second "Approve" action on another [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202278), resulting in its Approval:
3. Observed an immediately updated approve/reject count on the approved edit:

   > Rob Hruska approved 223 edit suggestions, and rejected 96 edit suggestions.

   <sup>This was to see if the edit counts were cached or delayed.</sup>
4. Improved a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202311) that had already received one "Approve" vote (also marked the edit as "helpful" when approving, but I doubt that matters).
5. Observed that the edit was approved by the first approver and Community.
6. Went back to one of my [previous actioned edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202278) and observed my approve/reject counts:

   > Rob Hruska approved 223 edit suggestions, and rejected 96 edit suggestions.

**If** the badge progress is solely calculated from the approve/reject counts I observed (which is just an assumption), it would appear that Improving a suggested edit **does not** increase the counts, and would therefore not count toward the badge.

---

If the above *is* true (that counts aren't increased), it seems that this would discourage the behavior that the Improve button encourages: users might be inclined to simply Approve an edit instead of Improve it (to receive the Reviewer badge progress). This would likely only be an issue if they already had the Copy Editor badge (since if they didn't, either action would count toward a badge).

Comment: Those numbers don't have to be the same numbers the code looks at for the badge, though. Overall, this business is a bit weird. For example, that snippet adds up to 223+96=319 decisions, but your [reviews tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska?tab=activity&sort=reviews) says 306.

Comment: @lunboks - That's correct, they may not be. I'm making that assumption with my post, but would love to be corrected by a dev if the assumption's not correct.

Comment: @lunboks - Also, interesting observation about the count differences. Hadn't noticed that. I'm gonna have to post another question about that.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122438/why-is-my-activity-tab-review-total-different-from-the-sum-of-my-accepted-reject