# Why is my Activity tab review total different from the sum of my accepted/rejected Reviewer Stats?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

In the title of my [Activity -> Reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska?tab=activity&sort=reviews) tab is my total review count. Currently:

> 306 Reviews

However, looking at my most [recent suggested edit approval](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202278), my approve/reject counts are:

> Rob Hruska approved 223 edit suggestions, and rejected 96 edit suggestions.

Which add up to **319**.

Why is there a difference between these two numbers? <sub>[Pointed out by lunboks here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122434/do-improved-suggested-edits-count-toward-the-proofreader-and-reviewer-badges#comment325462_122437)</sub>

---

This is tangential to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122434/do-improved-suggested-edits-count-toward-the-proofreader-and-reviewer-badges), since I don't know which number (if either) applies to the proofreader/reviewer badges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The count on your stats is an overall count, that's how many actions you had *total*...we don't want that going down when something happens to the post.

The count on your activity tab (as with *everything* there) is for **non-deleted** posts, that's a filter that's not applied to other overall stat on the suggested edit summary section.

Comment: That makes sense, but is a bit inconsistent with tag wikis. If those end up deleted, they still show up in the activity tab as a suggested edit on "", or "orphan tag wiki", depending on where you look.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for clarifying.