# Approve as too minor

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

This is going to be pretty short and somewhat to the point. I have a big problem with what goes on in the suggested edits section of /review. Obviously there is a lot of [mindless approval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything#comment430145_149621) going on, but I think that the other big problem here is the massive amount of "too minor" edits that are slipping through.

The argument has already been made that these edits still benefit the site, which of course is true. But, a lot of them technically are still too minor.

I propose a simple little "minor" check box next to the approve button that allows us to approve a minor edit but with a diminished reward the the editor. (1 or 0 rep for approval) I can't be the only one who's getting sick of having to reject people all day.

A couple more good examples of what @Bo Persson is talking about:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/769998
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/769827
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/769821

Comment: You don't have to reject, you can edit the post into better shape and untick the "suggested edit was helpful" box (if applicable - I always do if I have to edit more)

Comment: Interesting idea, but if there are already a lot of mindless approvals, I fear that people would just mindlessly ignore the check box and just approve.

Comment: Good point Ben, and @YannisRizos it's true that would probably happen, but I think it could still help those of us who are actually reviewing.

Comment: It doesn't help much if you try to reject it either http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/687660#./687660

Comment: @Ben: good idea in theory, not so good in practice. Mindless approving takes nearly no time or effort; actually improving requires both. By the time an improver finishes up, the bad edits are usually already approved. See [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted). [My answer to that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143242/131713) proposes some solutions.

Comment: I think this is still an issue. I'm currently approving edits which are nice, but pretty minor. I'd really like a way to mark them as minor.

Comment: @Yannis So have it automatically checked.

Comment: Relevant on SO meta, more recently (shameless self-plug): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/reviewer-overboard-or-a-request-to-improve-the-onboarding-guidance-for-new-revi/420357#420357

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this:

1. The meaning of "too minor" varies widely between individuals. Are trivial changes always too minor, or only too minor when they ignore other, more damning problems with the post? The edits you provide as examples illustrate this nicely - even the last one isn't problematic so much because it's *minor* but rather because it *introduces more problems than it fixes!*
2. Implemented as you describe, it's nothing more than a rep-denial mechanism. "I like your edit, but not enough to reward you for making it". There's no way to enforce its use in cases that actually justify it, meaning the actual application is likely to be seen as capricious. See also #1...

Note that there's an existing facility for preserving edits while marking them as "rejected": a checkbox on the "Improve" page. However, this suffers from both of the problems noted above *and* has the additional problem of edits being approved while a reviewer is improving them!

Fortunately, all of these problems can be solved... **Here's my solution:**

1. **Prevent pending edits from being reviewed by more than one reviewer at a time.** This is impossible to implement perfectly, but it *is* possible to hold reviews for a short period of time after one reviewer has started reviewing, thus ensuring that reviewers have a little bit of time to evaluate edits without being sniped by other, faster reviewers. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270169).
2. **Replace the "Improve" button with a new "More changes needed..." button.** This will produce a pop-up menu with two options:

   - **Approve suggestion then edit** will open the editor with the suggested revision, behaving as the current Improve does but lacks a checkbox. Submitting the edit approves the suggestion.
   - **Discard suggestion then edit** will open the editor with the *current* revision, implicitly rejecting the suggested edit with the following reason:

     > Your edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

     A link to the revision history should be provided if possible.

     [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with this UI:

     > [image: Approve, Improve Edit, Reject and Edit, Skip]
3. **Get rid of the "too minor" reject reason entirely.** If it's *really* too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, *then it isn't too minor!* [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I like number three.

Comment: Excellent ideas, one question though: rejections via "More changes needed" button would count towards the edit ban same way like the "Reject" button itself?

Comment: We don't lack review manpower nowadays (maybe we lack good reviewers, but that's a whole different kettle of fish). So we could go without “too minor” altogether. If an edit is really a waste of time, reject with a short but explanatory custom message. But “Accept and improve” must stay.

Comment: This is the most _sane_ thing I've seen in regards to this, since day 1. Let's do this.

Comment: Ah, now this is what it should have been all along! Keep “improve”, and fix “reject and improve” where we had to manually undo bad edits. Just a minor point: please don't make us click a menu with two options, put two different buttons “Improve” and “Discard and edit”.

Comment: @Gilles The bad reviewers aren't going to care whether the suggestions are minor or not, but the good ones likely are.  If they see that a continually increasing number of suggested edits are less and less valuable, they're more likely to be dis-heartened and stop reviewing, because after all what's the point of reviewing suggested edits if no meaningful percentage of the edits matter.

Comment: I suggest a more consistent wording of your choices after you click 'More changes needed...' I suggest labeling them **"Apply suggestion and edit"** and **"Discard suggestion and edit"**.

Comment: Why in earth did this took 2 years? We knew for 2 years that the whole review thing is fundamentally broken. It's still not enough to properly fix it, but I'm happy to see that *finally* a serious change is coming. I sincerely hope that more will follow. All those monkeys who are consistently degrading Stack Overflow since 2 years have completely killed my will to review and edit content.

Comment: There are more changes in the pipeline, @BalusC - sadly, the suggested edit code is a bit of a mess; it's a bolted-on system, and sometimes that makes it prohibitively hard to change. Knock on wood...

Comment: Looking forward it. Hopefully those changes are worth bigger bounties.

Comment: This is a *wonderful* idea, however the one problem I have is about the approve/deny mechanism. Sometimes, a person has made a few good corrections, but there's a *ton more* work to do. This would be 'too minor' (as there's a ton more work left), but why should I be forced to correct these items again, as 'rejecting' it would discard the edit?

Comment: It would be nice if "discard suggestion and edit" gave us the same rejection reasons to choose from as when rejecting outright. Sometimes a just plain *bad* edit is made on a post that still needs editing. In this case "did not correct critical issues" is not the true reason for rejection.

Comment: If you are providing an edit, you are providing an *example*, @air. That's really preferable to a canned reason, IMHO.

Comment: @Shog Fair enough - what I'm really getting at is that the implicit rejection reason you suggest above is potentially misinformative. If the choice of half a dozen canned reasons is not ideal, a one-size-fits-all canned reason is surely less so.

Comment: The "one size fits all" reason merely directs the reader to the revision history, @Air.

Comment: Not if it also presents "Your edit did not correct critical issues with the post" as the reason for rejecting the edit. It would be hard to make that reason *more* vague...

Comment: What's the specific concern here, @Air? That someone conscientious enough to follow the breadcrumbs back to the revision history and view a proper edit is going to come away failing to understand that code-formatting every other word isn't helpful? Gimme a scenario - and keep in mind, you're essentially suggesting I add more busywork for folks who are already putting in 10x more work than most reviewers, so there should be a *really good* reason for wanting it.

Comment: My specific concern is that users who suggest outright inappropriate edits -- not "too minor" revisions -- will find it difficult to intuit what they did wrong if the reviewer additionally makes an unrelated edit. Having your edit rejected is a valuable learning opportunity *provided the reason is explicit*. What you call busywork I think of more as due diligence.

Comment: Define "outright inappropriate", @Air.

Comment: E.g., suggested edit corrects syntax errors that are integral to the question, but misses several grammatical errors. If I click "discard suggestion and edit" and fix the grammar, there's no explanation of why the syntax errors needed to stay.

Comment: Unless you indicate such in your edit summary, @air. Which you may or may not do. Regardless, there is no "fixed integral errors" dismissal reason, nor is there likely to be one - if you wish to be that specific, you'll have to compose a reason on the spot regardless of how you proceed.

Comment: I'm not reviewing, but if I were then I'd be bothered by 3: now suddenly reviewers are forced to edit themselves (or skip, putting the minor edit in the hands of robo-reviewers)? (cc. @RobertH)

Comment: You're not *forced* to do anything, @arjan - though I might *encourage* you to [help pick better reject reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected)...

Comment: But wouldn't "too minor" still be the best reason to reject suggestions that are just that? I guess it would be weird to select a different reason, if one encounters it but one doesn't feel like editing themselves. (Maybe especially for posts that are beyond repair, or plain off topic, but from which someone still just removed some "Thanks". But then, maybe those who review are willing to improve edits.)

Comment: We need a way to Reject and build upon the edit made. I see often people changing some `i` to `I` (or other minor changes that don't improve the question/answer) but don't correct some more obvious formatting/indentation problems that would really improve a question/answer. What I do now is "Improve", copy all, cancel, Reject and Edit, paste and edit the rest. Cumbersome.

Comment: If the changes you're preserving are really worth all that trouble, @Jonathan... Then why not just Improve Edit? I've found that posts which require additional extensive editing are rarely worth preserving a few typo fixes - chances are, I'll be re-writing the entire sentences surrounding them anyway. If that's *not* true, you're effectively taking someone else's work without attribution, which is widely seen as a faux pas - the fact that we *ever* allowed this was probably due more to the tacked-on nature of the feature (Improve + Reject was not originally possible) than anything sane.

Comment: It's only the "best reason" if reviewers agree on what it means - and what it doesn't. That's *never* been true - a handful of y'all took it to mean one thing, another group another, and a majority of reviewers appear to have thought it referred to edits that were *not technically possible to even submit*. Inconsistent handling of edits is a recipe for angst, which is *exactly* what we've seen for the past several years. [Time for changes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected)

Comment: I won't Improve Edit someone's edit when they missed obvious things. If I was doing that, I would give them the rep and pass the message that their bad edit are ok and they should keep doing them, which isn't the goal of reviews (or is it?). If that's what the reviews are coming to, I'll stop doing them.

Comment: Everyone misses *something* sooner or later, @Jonathan. The question is, does the suggestion make a substantive enough improvement that simply discarding it would be a waste, or is it so trivial / pointless / unhelpful that throwing it away is no great loss. Discussing this in abstract is always somewhat difficult, so I'll provide an example of what I'm talking about: [worth preserving](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5734009) vs. [not worth preserving](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5733971).

Comment: Agree on the second one. The first one is a borderline, changing code is not something I agree on but on rare cases. I had [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5730058) that is of the like I reject but would keep the little things to improve upon. The question doesn't improve enough with the fixes that were made (debatable but it ain't unreadable) but the code is a mess and making it more readable does improve it a lot more IMO.

Comment: Agree that changing code is controversial, @Jonathan - but that's a separate discussion. FWIW, I'm firmly on the side of "approve what improves" when it comes to reviewing edits, regardless of how.

Comment: @Shog9 Wasn't part of the idea behind "too minor" to classify edits that could be right but not worth enough to be worthy of the reviewer time? Like if you correct casing in a product name (sharePoint) or such... do it but please wait until you don't require approval.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist the thing is that people conflated "waste my time" with "I don't care", which resulted in a behavior that came at odds with SE philosophy: If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!

Comment: I totally disagree with the argument about us editing to fix poor suggested edits over and over. Sure sometimes it's fine, eg editor missed a few things or whatever, I approve and edit many times, but what when they're just plain lazy, or getting rep like they're told to because they cannot comment without a care for quality? Low hanging fruit, and you want reviewers to spend their time fixing what lazy users cannot be bothered to do? That's not right imo. (But I know the answer to that, as always I can stop reviewing :rolleyes:)

Comment: Regarding 3 "*reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over, then it isn't too minor!*" Huh? So if they edit 6 chars, make lowercase "I" to upper, then the reviewer changes loads of things, then it wasn't too minor? In many cases on SO the edit suggester was either not seasoned, or (more often) lazy and rep hunting with low hanging fruit. With no care for the general quality or improvement towards the site or care for fellow users who have to review who *apparently* should also pick up the slack for them too? Around MSE it's said if you suggest an edit make it worthwhile.

Comment: Don't see what the problem is, @james. How long does it take you to upper-case an I? If it's longer than 0.5 seconds, get a better keyboard. So you hit "reject and edit", upper-case the I, and then make whatever other edits are necessary... You're out half a second, and the editor learns to look for other issues before hitting submit.

Answer (score 23):

Minor edits (that only include positive changes) should be approved but with no rewards given, and possibly, all edits should be considered minor unless otherwise stated (by the reviewers). I have never subscribed to the idea of edits being too minor because it leads to subjective review decisions (some reviewers are understandably more lenient than others even though rejecting minor edits is generally a safe decision to make, given the current policy).

This will solve the following issues:

1. time wasted for deliberating whether minor edits are too minor.
2. time wasted for improving minor edits so that they are no longer minor
3. pple losing sleep over minor edits being too rewarding
4. helpful edits being rejected for being too minor

Answer (score 16):

This proposal assumes that getting free, quick rep is the goal of people who suggest minor edits. (Otherwise, reducing the rep reward wouldn't be an effective solution.) Let's say that we do reduce the reward all the way down to zero, not just one.

That wouldn't solve the problem, because people would still get the regular two-rep reward from reviewers who didn't use the "too minor" checkbox. We wouldn't actually be getting rid of the rep incentive at all; we'd only be reducing the probability of receiving rep for any given suggestion. If anything, it'll make the problem **worse**, as people start to submit *a higher volume of suggestions* to compensate for the reduced probability of reward per suggestion, and individual suggestions get even worse because the suggesters don't want to increase the amount of time they spend on rep farming.

Getting away from the rep argument, this would also teach people that submitting minor edits, while not ideal, is still acceptable. That seems contrary to the usual goal of getting people to fix all the problems in the posts they edit.

Answer (score 9):

I already mentioned this idea in a previous discussion. So I'm in favor.

With any minor edit, I try to save the effort by adding some extra edits, but it isn't always possible. And there are still a lot of posts needing good edits so anyone who wants to earn their 500 times 2 rep have all the possibilities in the world.

// Private rant space:
Then again, there are still a lot of bad edit suggestions. (adding thank you, change `I` to `i` to mention a few)

Comment: "adding thank you, change I to i to mention a few" sounds unlikely. Are you sure those aren't concurrency issues?

Comment: I have seen several of them.  2 today, maybe concurrency, but they counted as suggested edits.

Comment: I suspect they simply edited a version where the "thank you" was still there, and somebody edited it out while they were editing it, making it seem like they added it back in.

Comment: Here is an example of a seemingly added thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/770684

Comment: There are people who do actually actively add "thank you" to posts.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ, do we have a spare giant I?

Comment: And here's an examnple of a I turned into a i: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/774981