# What are my options when I see a way too minor suggested edit approved?

Tags: discussion, support

[image]

Obviously, this suggested edit should never have been approved. Because it's very, very minor.

Is it acceptable for me to "rollback" this edit? Does the suggested editor lose the +2 rep when I roll it back? Should I comment on one of his questions, explaining not to make too minor edits like this?

Is there anything I should do to notify the reviewers that approved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4161638) too minor suggested edit?

Comment: Step one: cry in anger. Step two: bring a hammer down on those reviewers... and throw something at them, while you're at it. :P

Comment: Did it fix every problem? If the thanks was the only issue, the edit to remove it was not too minor.

Comment: IMO if you're removing the "I thank you all" then you should be removing the "I apologise for the long post", especially when that's the only thing you're changing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the reputation will not be refunded. Rolling it back doesn't help either: all you'll do is create another revision activity and the post will not be improved (you'll be making the same fault the user that suggested it, did).

My usual approach here is to

1. Fix the post myself.
2. Review the suggested user's history.
3. Leave a comment somewhere if it's still acceptable.

   1. Remove the comment once I believe he saw it.
4. Custom flag the user if it is pretty bad (with a few examples linked).
5. Review the approvers their history (usually I just pick one with the worst A/R ratio).

   1. Custom flag with a few examples if it's recurring behaviour.

Comment: you can @-reply the editor on the post in question, which is better than your 2/3. That will help the source of the bad edits but doesn't stop the robo reviewers who approve them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following: how does notifying the editor stop the robo reviewers? I address both issues throughout my process as far as I can see, with the exception for cases where it seems to be a standalone event.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian no, with their id. It will appear not to work (you don't get autocomplete) but it will

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that with the changes to the edit review system, "Too Minor" was removed as a reject reason in [mid 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) because the definition of too minor was very inconsistent.  So in that sense there is no longer an edit that is considered "too minor", and the responsibility for addressing is pushed to the reviewers to make a decision on how best to handle.

1. Does the post even need fixing?  And does the edit improve the post by making it more clear, easier to read, and/or fixing grammar/spelling?  If not, then reject as "no improvement whatsoever"
2. Does the edit fix everything?  Is there anything left to fix?  If not **and you are willing to finish the edit yourself** then you should either click "Improve" or "Reject and Edit".  Don't just reject because you think someone is farming rep with minor edits.  I'll refer back to #1 first (does the edit improve the post - if so then it is useful even if it isn't complete).

Now nothing in the above even remotely covers your actual question because your asking about what to do when a "too minor" edit is approved. But the reason I covered the background is it helps set the stage for what to do after it is approved.  And the solution is literally restarting #1 above.

- Is the post easier to read (or find in the case of tag edits)?  If
  so, then leave it alone.
- Did the edit make the post harder to read?  If so, then roll it back.

Now if you find someone approving a lot of bad edits, then your only recourse is to flag for a moderator and provide some specifics on the bad edits they were approving.

Comment: How about 100 per day? Would that be "a reoccurring pattern"?

Comment: The comment you linked to is gone.

Comment: @PrincessLuna thanks, I'll remove the link.  But as I recall, there wasn't much said in it that I didn't paraphrase in my post