# How to reverse a bad suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Is there a way (besides going back and editing a post to where it was before) to reverse a suggested edit that is incorrect? In some cases, I could see going back and editing taking time if there are a lot of changes. Additionally, if it's less than 4 characters, you can't do it, so that would require some "extra" edit, which is kind of silly.

Here's the post in question (for anyone who can *read the question* to LOL at). Alternate caption: "why is there a Microsoft in my UNIX desktop?" See also: *Windows vs. window vs. window - KNOW THE DIFFERENCE.* :)

[image: WATLOLSRSLY]

Comment: Yes, rollback is the way to go. One click to roll the post back to any previous revision. But it requires 2K reputation (same privilege as editing other users posts) and I see you don't have it just yet, so I fear you don't have that shortcut. What you can do it go to revisions list, click "source" under desired revision and suggest this as new edit, making it clear why you're doing it.

Comment: Rollback is an option. Refer to [this recent discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223050/what-are-my-options-when-i-see-a-suggested-edit-like-this-approved) for more thoughts.

Comment: Keep in mind that if this actually should be *Windows Server* instead of *Window Server*, then it might be a suitable edit since everything else seems in order.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel But it shouldn't. It can't be. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just edited it directly (no need to suggest the reversion as an edit), but it's good to know that once you have the rep there is a shortcut.

Comment: @minitech sorry, but removing the protocol causing the images not to show in the app (iOS but most likely android as well) so until it's fixed, better leave the protocol. (going to report the bug now)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Does it work as HTTPS?

Comment: @minitech yes, that's not the issue though. The app will become more and more popular so we don't want to break pictures in it. :) (it works for me because I don't block mixed contents, but you're right that it will show broken image for those who do block. There is already a feature request about it. Oh, it's yours! :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, I mean does the HTTPS protocol work in the app, as opposed to no protocol?

Comment: @minitech yep, writing from app now and can see the picture.

Comment: So my question about rollbacks has been rolled back? That means that this is now Meta-Meta-SO. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rollback the post in the post revisions page. Then you scroll down a bit, and you can see rollback link in grey background(after the newest edit). You can find more from rollabacking here:  [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)