# Image without protocol in its URL is broken in app (iOS and likely android)

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, ios-app

The [following question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223183/how-to-reverse-a-bad-suggested-edit) contains a screenshot:

> [image]

So far so good. The image URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbSu.png and as attempt to make it show in https as well, someone edited the protocol out, leaving only `//i.stack.imgur.com/xMbSu.png` as the URL. Now this works perfectly in any browser, but problem is the app is not a browser so it's showing broken image: (with the `alt` as text)

> [image]

Can this please be fixed?

Test case: (it is without a protocol, use to reproduce the bug)

[image]

iOS app version 0.1.21 for me, if android app user can also confirm please do and let me know.

Comment: Surprisingly, it all works as designed - no protocol means "use the same protocol", so it also means "don't use any protocol when viewed in a way that does not involve any"... App did exactly what editor told it to do. Of course it's not what we want or expect, but technically it is the only valid result.

Comment: @Mołot the app should add protocol manually, the bug is in the app not in the HTML or anything else.

Comment: From the "what would I want to see happening" point of view you are right. From the "what section 4.2 of RFC 3986 says" current behavior seems proper (if unwanted) and the bug is in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 0.1.23.

This was an interesting problem.  The page was loading with no base URL.  Providing the question/answer link as a base URL fixed image loading but broke prettify which was loaded from a `file:///` URL.  I ended up setting up an [NSURLProtocol](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/) to serve prettify off a custom hostname.

Comment: Cheers, didn't imagine it's so complex behind the scenes! :)

Comment: Installed 0.1.23 now and confirm it is fixed.