# Tapping on tag markdown in preview leads to unknown page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, markdown-preview

**Description:**

Create a question draft with tag markdown, then tap on the tag in the preview. It would go to an unknown page. Copying the link on that page crashes the app.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left draw, tap Ask Question.
2. Tap the site icon in front of the question title and choose Meta Stack Overflow.
3. In Question title, type something.
4. In Question body, type `[meta-tag:ios-app]`, which would create the tag markdown: [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app).
5. Tap Preview.
6. In the preview, tap the tag hyperlink (which, you can see if you long tap on it, links to something like applewebdata://3BDA5FAD-8759-4E78-BCC5-72CC63C07147/questions/tagged/ios-app).
7. Now it goes to a weird page with a title as a UUID.
8. Tap the action button on the lower right, then choose Copy link.
9. The app crashed.

**Actual Results:**

Tapping on tag in preview leads to unknown page.

**Expected Results:**

Tapping on tag in preview should do a search on the tag.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.27, v0.1.28
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

**Notes:**

- No problem for normal tags like `[tag:ios]`: [ios](/questions/tagged/ios). However, same bug even for normal tags when choosing to post question to non-meta Stack Overflow.

<sup>Post created on [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) v1.0.28 (and later edited on Desktop)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Whenever a question or answer is rendered, the real post's URL is used as the base URL for the web view (See [Image without protocol in its URL is broken in app (iOS and likely android)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223199/image-without-protocol-in-its-url-is-broken-in-app-ios-and-likely-android)).

The problem we had here was that previews don't have URL's to go off of, so we'll be using the site URL if we don't have anything more localized.

This also led to a discussion about whether links should even work in preview because you can end up in a rabbit hole where you can explore the entire app in the preview, maybe even a preview within a preview within a preview.  To avoid having the app deal with the metaphysical consequences of inception, links within previews will now take you to the browser if you click through to validate them.

Comment: Verified fixed in 0.1.29. Nice to know the explanation.