# Lot of too minor suggested edits

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I was reviewing suggested edits and found lot of minor edits from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148314/annarbor87). Every time, the user was just removing a few words (like "Thank you" at the end of the message). But the edits were approved by other people! I find it too minor and it looks like the user is only trying to get reputation and not trying to improve anything on Stackoverflow.

Do I misunderstand what a "too minor" suggested edit is?

Additional remark: it also looks like this user got suddenly a lot of upvotes which looks suspicious to me. Does the system automatically handle this?

The approved suggested edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4172046
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4172049

Comment: There is a script that runs daily to detect and reverse serial voting.

Comment: They "earned" mortarboard from serial upvoting.

Comment: Wow, [that history is pretty absurd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1148314/annarbor87?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Pages upon pages of just removing 'thanks'. In this case I would personally flag one of these reviews, and add a custom message for the mod explaining the offending behavior and ask them to look at it.

Comment: I think there should be an automatic ban for suggested edits and automatic revert of suggested edit reputation for that day. As soon as 2 or 3 suggested edits are rejected in a day, you cannot edit anymore for that day. There will still be minor edit going through the review process. But not all suggested edits from this kind of user are approved. Quite quickly they would get banned for the day.

Comment: *"Do I misunderstand what a "too minor" suggested edit is?"* - if the taglines he removed was the only part of the post that needed to be fixed then his edit was not too minor. Only if there was other things left his edits was inappropriate.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian what you say is against what appears to be consensus [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/225745). Most voted answers says there should be no things like that in posts. 3rd most voted is the first one that says when to remove them, and it tells to remove them always (unless OP rolls them back). Of course you are free to provide your own answer there and start collecting votes on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually left a comment for that same user yesterday. [View it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026811/auto-page-create-from-template#comment33395074_22026811)

You are right, he has done a lot of too minor suggested edits.

Actually, he's part of the reason I started this thread yesterday. [What are my options when I see a way too minor suggested edit approved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223050/what-are-my-options-when-i-see-a-suggested-edit-like-this-approved)

---

To your second part, about the upvotes. Yea, those really do look strange.

It seems like the votes are often all within 1-3 minutes of each other and then usually stop for the day.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following change in the Reputation system for editing:

For the case an edit gets rejected as too trivial then maybe should remove `-1` reputation from the editor.

- So a good edit: `+2`
- a too trivial rejected edit: `-1`

==> should still be enough incentive to edit something, but after having received your 3rd `-1` the editor may start thinking about not doing the trivial edits anymore.