# Edit reviewers don't know how to review because nobody told them!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I recently created a [Stack Overflow chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58120/please-dont-approve-minor-or-invalid-edits) to whip low-quality edit reviewers into shape.

It… worked. Most of them said they would be more careful about minor/invalid/vandalism edits and that they didn't know minor edits were bad: after my complaining, they **improved**.

That leads me to think that edit reviewers should be educated more.

> [image: Reject those you know are wrong]

Is that ^ supposed to mean anything? Come on, there should be a Help Center article at the very least. A screen that needs to be manually clicked through that explains reject reasons and informs reviewers about how the system works would be even better.

Comment: They weren't called out before. Certainly not invited to a room about the behaviour. That's the difference. Otherwise even with all the warnings and messages they would continue because it was a system message.

Comment: @random Well, the warnings and messages could still be improved, even if that requires a "chat with an expert" type interfaces… :P

Comment: Would be nice to have some clarification over what is "too minor" (which has different unwritten rules depending on the age of the post) and if we should be rejecting tag-only edits that are technically correct but aren't dealing with the major tags on a post.

Comment: Minor edits aren't that bad, and I see waaaay too many edits rejected on the ridiculous basis of "minorness". I'm sorry to see that you're going to make that _worse_.

Comment: @Troyen: _Any_ technically valid edit should be accepted, IMO. "You didn't fix this other thing too" is a frankly stupid reason to reject improvement.

Comment: I agree (begrudgingly) with @LightnessRacesinOrbit  minor edits are fine. If it takes ten edits to fix up a question, or just one, I don't care. As long as the edits are made, what's the problem? The edit queue is always under control.

Comment: Well I don't mind so much if we discourage users without edit rights from submitting edit suggestions that are really minor, as that _does_ clog up the queue. However, _rejecting_ such edits outright seems counterproductive, and going further by discouraging high-rep users from these edits (as I see on meta frequently) is just offensively stupid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) That's the rules, period. 2) Minor edits clog not just the edit queue, they also can be used to game the reputation system. 3) Bumping questions excessively is a problem. 4) There's no real reason why minor edits *should* get thru. Any positive effects are… minor, and reject-improving isn't hard.

Comment: @bjb568: 1) On a subsite dedicated to discussing and _improving_ the rules, what sort of ridiculous logic is that?! 2) High rep users do not "game" the reputation system through edits; they neither want nor need to. 3) No, it's not. 4) I already addressed that: improvement is improvement, no matter how small.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) Oh, you can dispute it on meta, but you have to follow the current rules while reviewing. 2) No, low rep users game the system by taking advantage of the fact that almost any edit can go thru the system or roboreviewers. 3) From my experience of the home page, it is. 4) I addressed that to: It isn't an improvement if it encourages, essentially, gaming the system.

Comment: @bjb568: 1) The rules do not define "too minor" clearly enough for you to use that as an argument against anything I've said; my interpretation of a valid "too minor" reject is one that rejects BrE->AmE. 2) So what? If the edit is valid, it's valid, and they deserve the rep. If they only made the edi to get rep, so what? That's why we _have_ rep: incentive. If they're trying to game with bad edits, it doesn't matter: they're bad edits, so reject. Again, then, irrelevant argument. 3) Explain. 4) [Yes, it still is.](http://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) "This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post." 2) Nobody "deserves" reputation. 3) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25409935/revisions) bumped the post to *first* on my front page. 4) Ok, fine, if you really want to keep the edit, push the improve button.

Comment: @bjb568: 1) Right, weasel words. All vague and subjective. No specifics whatsoever, beyond "multiple" which yes I will choose to entirely ignore because that text is just wrong. "Minor", "substantive". 2) Everybody who adds value deserves reputation. That is the entire point....?! 3) You've _still_ not explained why this is such a bad thing, only asserted so. If you hate the post so much, don't worry, because it'll get knocked off within minutes. 4) No, because I don't have time to improve it. You're still obsessed with this idea of all or nothing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) "Multiple" is **the rule**. You don't really have a choice, unless you want to be review banned. 2) Nobody "deserves" reputation. They happen to *earn* reputation thru their actions. (and thru roboreviewers) 3) Bad posts shouldn't be on the front page. 4) If you don't have time to review properly, please don't review.

Comment: @bjb588: 2) By definition, if you earn reputation through good actions, then good actions lead to deserving rep. 3) "Bad" is subjective, and somebody just improved a post, so bumping it may encourage others to finish the job. This is a good thing. Bad posts can never be improved if no-one ever sees them. 4) Stupid thing to say, totally ignores everything we've already discussed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 2) People *tend* to earn reputation through good actions, no logical conclusion possible. 3) Bad is to be graded in review, in particular in the suggested edit queue where ["too minor"](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2330409#2330409) should be applied to edits that make a negligible difference to a low quality post. You shouldn't try to spread bad questions everywhere so people improve them, they are deemphasize so good questions can be answered and viewed (and learnt from). 4) What do you mean? Do you want to encourage roboreviewing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/767/discussion-between-bjb568-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @bjb568: 4) What? No... Let's not continue this discussion at all because it's lost all logic!

Comment: More than having reviewers reject valid edits (I'm absolutely with @LightnessRacesinOrbit there) I'd rather have the reviewers put more effort into checking tag wiki edits for plagiarism. More often than not high rep users aren't even aware of the fact that a tag wiki entry that is a 1-to-1 Wikipedia copy is not only bad but of questionable legality.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I agree. Whoever wrote those reasons should be doomed to answer questions like this under a pseudonym for all eternity.

But enough about the past.

Nobody is gonna read a help center article. If they were, [they'd have already read it when they got notified of the privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). So here's what I think the guidance *should* be:

> - **Approve** edits that clearly improve the post
> - **Improve Edit** when you can make additional improvements to the post
> - **Reject and Edit** to replace an ineffective edit with your own substantive changes
> - **Reject** edits that fail to improve the post... or that make it *worse*
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

Comment: Ok, when are the changes going to be made?

Comment: In 6-8 weeks, newb

Comment: Can the tag wiki/excerpt have an special line: Reject edits that fail to improve the post, make it worse *or are plagiarization of other sources without proper attribution*.

Comment: Where do "too minor" edits fit into this? A minor edit may indeed improve the post, but they're not worth the time of edit reviewers so we want to discourage them by rejecting them. Maybe "clearly improve" should be "significantly improve".

Comment: And then the **Reject** condition should add "or only correct minor errors that do not impair understanding (grammar, punctuation, spelling, capitalization)"

Comment: They don't, @Barmar - [I'm redefining Too Minor as "it's easier for me to just discard your changes and make my own edit than it is to approve it"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039). Because *no one* could agree on what "too minor" actually meant.

Comment: I was about to post a "never mind", as I just noticed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected?newsletter=1&nlcode=233788%7c6b51

Comment: Uh… we're a little bit more than 6-8 weeks in, and [the guidance text still sucks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IIz8S.png).

Comment: Yeah, had a lot of other changes in the pipeline when this was written - never got back to it, @bjb568.

Comment: Dalgas got this in today!