# "~19 suggested edits pending approval" -> "There are no items for you to review."

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

Why there are `no items for you to review` while the counter fluctuates around 20 (never seen it that big)? I remember that the counter is not precise, but now it's way off.

After some page refreshes, it showed me a some reviews, but fewer than usual (the counter is still high).

Comment: Which *site?* I'm assuming SO, but for future reference this is all a lot easier to diagnose if you specify...

Comment: Yes, SO. The counter is still high. After refreshing it showed some reviews, but now it's again "no items for you".

Comment: The count appears to be off; [here's](http://i.imgur.com/RSuB3UV.png) a screenshot of the Review screen

Comment: The counter is still showing more suggedits than usual while the system presents me fewer suggedits that usual...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Geoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270145/why-number-of-suggested-edits-showing-different/270169#270169):

> A fix has been deployed.  We are now [doing a lot more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) to make sure that each person reviewing suggested edits has a good opportunity to accurately review them.
>
> It's a bit like ticketmaster, or any type of reservation system. When you visit a suggested edit review task it's now "checked out" to you for that time - the counter previously didn't reflect the amount of "checked out" tasks.