# Keyboard shortcuts for review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, keyboard-shortcuts

Could we have keyboard shortcuts for reviewing? Something to the effect of:

- <kbd>a</kbd> - Approve/Looks OK
- <kbd>e</kbd> - Edit
- <kbd>r</kbd> - Reject/Recommend Deletion
- <kbd>s</kbd> - Skip

Each of the queues do have their own options, so that makes it a little less cut-and-dry as to which keys should do what.

---

Now, you probably think this is a bad idea due to the existence of [robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits); however, the suggested edit queue [now locks questions to reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) for three minutes, which prevents the sniping issue.

In addition, I don't think that pressing <kbd>a</kbd> repeatedly will be *much* quicker than clicking "Accept" for robo-reviewers.

What say you?

Comment: Did people downvote this because it would be equally good for QoL of robo-reviewers as non-robo-reviewers? It's already easy enough to robo-review that giving keyboard shortcuts will probably not change the **amount** of robo-reviewing. If that's the only reason, I disagree. I would personally like to have this. If I was a robo-reviewer and wanted optimal quality of life, there are probably _way_ more effective ways to go hands free (but I don't want to give anyone ideas).

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that by reviewing you actually mean *reviewing* (editing, voting,  commenting, etc) and not just clicking buttons to earn badges. If you spend some time reviewing a post, spending half a second to click a button won't matter.

Keyboard shortcuts will just bring much more robo-reviewers and simplify their activity.

Is there any Particular Reason in implementation of keyboard shortcuts for review?