# Fully enable keyboard shortcuts in review queues

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/295232) quite often to vote posts up or down, and flagging or close-voting them.

In the review queues, especially the First Posts and Late Answers, where these kind of actions are encouraged, the keyboard shortcuts don't work.

I've noticed that they sometimes (but not always) work if you reload the page of a specific review item (but never on subsequent reviews). It seems related to loading the post into the page dynamically via AJAX.

Note that I'm not asking for [Keyboard shortcuts for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242001/keyboard-shortcuts-for-review-queues); IMHO that's a bad idea since it encourages robo-reviewing.