# Allow me to use the standard keyboard shortcuts for closing a question in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

It's almost impossible to review Close Votes from the review queues without a mouse.

For accessibility purposes, it would be much better if the same keyboard shortcuts that you'd use from the question would work in the queue.

Currently, it's very hard to select a close reason. Allowing me to go <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> (for example) in the queue would be much better than having to fool around with double-right clicking to get the focus in the right place.

<sub>If you're confused as to why it's important that things be accessible without the mouse, please read up on [keyboard accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). While I thankfully don't have any physical problems with using 
a mouse, I'm using my time with a broken mouse to give accessibility feedback so that people who need it can get a better site experience.</sub>

Comment: Related: [Keyboard shortcuts for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242001/333472)

Comment: Userscript to add keyboard shortcuts to the cvq: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/CloseVoteShortcuts.user.js

Comment: If you refresh the page, you can use <M> <C> etc.; see [Enable keyboard shortcuts in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315782/295232)

Answer (score 3):

I like this idea... though I do see a minor issue that could result from it: it puts power into the hands of roboreviewers.  It seems (though I could be wrong) that if a robo-reviewer can VTC in 1 second instead of 5, it will make them that much more likely to do it.

Getting a badge at the price of (6 x 20) seconds a day (2 minutes) is a higher price to pay than (2 x 20) seconds per day (less than a minute).

Obviously, the rebuttal is clear: robo-reviewers will do what they will do, and this could make it even easier to catch them at it, since it is impossible that someone is doing good reviews with an average time of 2 seconds.

Bottom line: I like the idea, but I do think we should proceed with caution.

Comment: This could be easily prevented by limiting close votes within a certain time period (*"You can only cast one close vote every 5 seconds"*). There are plenty of similar limitations on flagging, voting, and deleting comments.

Comment: Hmm, nice.  Clean and simple.  Wish I thought of that myself.  :)