# When suggestion is rejected in Improve/Edit, why are reviewer's stats not displayed?

Tags: support, user-interface, rejected-edits

When a reviewer picks "Improve" and indicates that suggestion wasn't helpful, an edit gets rejected. In suggestion record page, when one clicks *(more)*, only stats for Community user and suggestor are shown. What is the reason that reviewer stats aren't displayed in this case?

An [example of such an edit is here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75548):

> gnat reviewed this 17 hours ago: Edit
>   Community♦ reviewed this 17 hours ago: Reject
>   Conflicted with a subsequent edit.

When one clicks *(more)*, page shows only one reviewer:

> **Reviewer Stats**
>
> Community has approved 1219 edit suggestions and rejected 303 edit suggestions

---

I wonder because in case of straight rejection, without Improve, both reviewer stats are shown. In [this example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75605), with two straight rejects, clicking *(more)* shows both reviewers:

> **Reviewer Stats**
>
> gnat has approved 392 edit suggestions and rejected 233 edit suggestions
>    KeesDijk has approved 47 edit suggestions and rejected 14 edit suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't approve or reject the suggested edit, you *replaced* it with your own (through the *Improve* option). This isn't quite the same as voting to reject the edit; rather it is a new edit that is seeded with the suggestion.

Community then rejected the original suggestion, because your edit replaced it.

Comment: but the page says, "gnat **reviewed** this 17 hours ago" - I read this as one who picked Improve is considered a reviewer, right? why not show stats in this case?

Comment: @gnat: you reviewed but didn't vote. Improving is effectively a veto, by bypassing the normal voting path. It requires a moderator to veto, so Community does this on your behalf.

Comment: interesting. How comes that indicating that suggestion wasn't helpful doesn't count as vote?

Comment: @gnat: because Community executes that vote, and as a moderator it is a binding vote.

Comment: ...oh wait I think I got it. Replace is the word here, I see. [Allow me to accept an answer immediately!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47448/165773) :)