# Reviewer stats on a suggested edit incorrectly show me as approving and rejecting 0 suggested edits overall

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

For [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6043727) review, I clicked "Reject and Edit" and found that the post was edited while I was in the middle of editing (only after I finished editing did I find out the edit was approved). However, after I finished the edit, I found something rather fishy:

[image: 0 approved and rejected?!]

As you can see, the stats on that particular review seem to show that I have neither approved nor rejected any reviews at all, though that's very much untrue (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6043873)
 review shows 713 approved and 860 rejected as of this post).

Comment: There's also the matter of how the "Reject and Edit" managed to come after 3 "Approves", but I'm willing to believe that what happened was 1) I got the review in my queue 2) a few minutes passed, allowing the third person to review and approve 3) I finish the review

Comment: related: [When suggestion is rejected in Improve/Edit, why are reviewer's stats not displayed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238792/165773)

Answer (score 2):

The bug appears to be that the actual reviewer in case of "Reject and Edit" is the Community account, as can be see clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6030341):

> [image]

In case of the specific review you linked to, it's an edge case where you submitted the edit after the edit was already approved, so you didn't really review it.

Comment: I don't know about it being an "edge case." Twice now it's happened to me on Physics ([a](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71838), [b](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71987)) without any other reviewers involved.

Comment: @Kyle good point. Guess the bug is more severe than I first thought then!