# Reviewer stats showing wrong details when community user reviewed before others

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits, community-user

I've reviewed [a suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23408) here on meta.

Community user approved the edit while I was reviewing. Now, the issue is in the reviewer stats where it's showing only the community user had reviewed the post.

[image]

I think, this issue will be reproduced whenever the community user approved edit while others reviewing. We should fix this.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, you want it to show the stats of the person who improved? I think the "bug" is probably by-design, but I think it's a fair feature-request.

Comment: @OGHaza, yup I'd improved the edit by marked it as helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and not a bug. When a reviewer opts to further improve a suggested edit then it is marked as *approved* (or *rejected*) by the community user and the actual reviewer is mentioned as the *editor* in the review summary.

At the bottom of review screen there is a checkbox labelled as **Suggested edit was helpful**.  If it is *checked* then review summary will show *approved* by the Community user otherwise it will say *rejected* by the Community user.

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80550/):

> I wanted a simple way to track all the edits that are approved through
>   "improve", it is still easy to track who caused it, cause they are the
>   editors of the revision directly after it.