# How does improving a "suggested-edit" work?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This question kind of proceeds from [a comment I made on another thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85758/instant-approval-of-revisions-for-users-with-edit-privileges/89103#89103) yesterday.  At the time I commented I had just been blocked from editing but I hadn't explored the functionality further.

I have just used the *improve* feature for the first time.  I edited the pending edit, then when I pressed *save* the revised question was posted, with me as the latest changer.  I wasn't expecting that.  I now read the relevant [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) but it doesn't discuss *improve*.

I have gone into the question and the edit history lists the junior editor and me as two separate changes.  So, my question is, does this mean the junior editor still gets credit (i.e. the two rep points) for their contribution to the revised text?

And, as I type, a second question occurs to me: doesn't this behaviour subvert the whole "two votes to approve" thang?

---

I'm tagging this as a bug because I think the FAQ ought to be clearer.  Yet seemed too trivial for a feature-request.

Comment: Yes, the original editor gets the credit.

Comment: Did the fact that you can edit the FAQ yourself to include the missing information escape you? How ironic...

Comment: retagging this as discussion, feel free to edit the FAQ if you wish

Comment: @CodyGray - I fear your understanding of irony is on a par with that of Alanis Morisette.  I don't understand how the *Improve* function works. That's why I'm asking the question.  So it would be irresponsible of me to edit the FAQ to address the topic.

Comment: @Waffles - incidentally, I edited my question yesterday (minor spelling) for which I got +2 rep.  Is that correct?

Comment: @APC the 2 rep was for accepting my answer :)

Comment: @Waffles - I have edited the FAQ using information from this thread.

Comment: @Waffles - duh, of course it was 8-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [D]oes this mean the junior editor still gets credit (i.e. the two rep points) for their contribution to the revised text?

Yes, it does ... you can [review the list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?tab=improved&filter=day) if you have 10k and look for any patterns of abuse. I see no abuse there.

> And, as I type, a second question occurs to me: doesn't this behaviour subvert the whole "two votes to approve" thang?

Well, in my opinion, no. What this means is that if you are willing to go the extra mile and further improve a post you are given special privileges. Everything is traceable back to you if you abuse the system. We can find all the people that have an itchy trigger finger on the improve button.

Comment: I presume the Improve feature is open to any 10k user?

Comment: Or is it any user with full edit rights?

Comment: @APC its available to all people with full edit rights