# Make pending edits visible when they are limited to the presentation

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I understand [why we need multiple approvals for suggested edits to take effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81510/175984). However, there is an important sub-category of edits, where the changes are limited to altering the presentation of the content without touching its substance. For example, editing whitespace or adding markdown does not usually<sup>*</sup> alter the meaning of the question or the answer, only its presentation.

I think that it is safe to show these edits right away, before they get approved by two reviewers. This would make the question legible right away, but keep the rest of the approval process in place to ensure the quality of the approved edits does not go down.

---

<sup>*</sup> I say "usually" because there are programming languages where the indentation is considered part of a program semantic.

Comment: How do you define the difference between the two?

Comment: * but then you're also saying it's dangerous to show it without approval?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Checking the results of running a `diff` should be sufficient. SO has smart programmers, I'm 100% sure they can figure it out for >99% of the cases.

Comment: @Arjan Where am I saying that?

Comment: In your own footnote, *"there are programming languages where the indentation is considered part of a program semantic"*.

Comment: @Arjan I'm not saying that it **is** dangerous, only that it **may** in some corner cases change the meaning (in which case the usual approval process will quickly straighten things out).

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with this, also aesthetic edits can alter the substance of a question, for example the indentation.One may edit a post altering the indentation and make it worse.

Why should one do that? We can't know, users with low reputation haven't still demonstrated to be genuine.Or they may be ignoring indentation rules.

Comment: That is why I suggest leaving in place the current review process. Making "indent-only" fixes visible right away does not free them from being reviewed.

Comment: Right, or folks adding `<kbd>`, shiver! However, I *would* auto-accept edits that add proper paragraphs. Why do you keep using line breaks?

Comment: @Arjan A paragraph is a unit of homogeneous content. I make another paragraph only when I change topic.

Comment: [Really?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/160503/1)

Comment: Well you said that I "keep using line breaks", that link is in the past. I write a paragraph per topic, that's how all schools teach it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, but I'm quite sure schools in Italy don't teach you to break up a paragraph into multiple sub-parts using line breaks, if that's what you're trying to say? And on the web (and in Markdown), paragraphs are simply not created by enforcing a line break, aka `<br>`. Note that others have been editing some of your posts to make corrections too. But well, I've said all I could. Watch for missing whitespace after full stops as well! Cheers.

Comment: @Arjan I meant they teach the rules of when doing it, not how to do it in HTML. I understand that this way it's better visible, so thanks.