# 20k users can vote to delete negatively voted accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

20k users can vote to delete answers with a score of -1 or lower (at any time, I believe), but the voting lacks a check to see if the answer is an accepted answer. IIRC, accepted answers have to be unaccepted before being deleted, even by mods, so such a delete vote should be disallowed completely.

As a test a while ago, I voted to delete [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits/78331#78331), and just now also voted on [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go/82872#82872)... for fun, I guess.

Since the first one was Jeff's post, I commented on it, but that didn't draw much attention, so I'm posting this. Of course this isn't a huge bug, but it should be fixed eventually.

<sub>(Admittedly, I'm very curious to see if 3 delete votes would actually delete the answer and break things horribly. I suspect at least the former would happen.)</sub>

Comment: I added another delete vote for you.  Here's to horribly breaking the system!

Comment: I would finish the business, but I'm just a little short of reputation...

Comment: nothing will break but we probably should not allow you to vote to delete accepted answers

Comment: Mods actually can delete accepted answers

Comment: If someone accepts a *really* bad answer, why *shouldn't* 20k-users be able to delete it?

Answer (score 12):

As Michael [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83356/20k-users-can-vote-to-delete-negatively-voted-accepted-answers/286049?noredirect=1#comment204038_83356), moderators are not restricted from deleting accepted answers... And neither are 20K users. The restriction applies only to the author of the answer itself. [A debatable restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances) that has nevertheless probably prevented some amount of abuse over the years.

(Posting this answer to replace [an inaccurate one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336594/non-moderator-can-delete-accepted-answer) from five years prior)

Comment: Did you delete a previously-accepted answer on this very question? Inquiring minds want to know!