# Pending pointless edit proposals blocking real edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we need a 'reject and improve' button'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button)

As it is today, a pending edit will block all other edits until it is either rejected or approved. The answer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits) very related question states that we should use the `improve` button for situations like this, and suggest an improvement of the previous edit. This would be good, except hitting improve also means that the previous edit is automatically accepted, which is not desirable when the pending edit is pointless or even wrong.

Personally, I don't like hovering around a poorly formatted question waiting for the pending edit to be dealt with just so that I can edit it properly, so in cases like this I usually just hit "reject edit" and move on. What I find whenever I return to that question later, though, is that it's usually still in the same sorry state as it was when I left it. This could have been fixed, if I was only allowed to post a proper edit when I wanted to.

A forth option, besides "approve", "reject" and "improve", such as "**provide new suggestion**", would come in handy here, as it would allow me to edit the question in a meaningful way, while not giving any credit to the editor who provided the pointless edit.

Comment: This fourth option would also complicate things even more...

Comment: @alex Could you maybe elaborate on that a little bit?