# Unable to edit posts with rejected/approved edits

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we need a 'reject and improve' button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button)

The following seems like a regression of [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits):

A post has a pending edit which I *rejected*. I would then like to edit/improve this post, however, this is not possible. Instead, a popup showing the (rejected) edit is displayed.

It seems that I must wait until the pending edit is removed from the editing queue until I am able edit the post again.

Update: The same problem exists, when one already has a *approved* a suggested edit, and the edit is still pending.

Comment: Why not improve it directly instead of cancelling out the other users' effort?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Surely this would have been the simpler way, but - it just happened.  Besides, the same problem exists when one *approved* a suggested edit.

Comment: Yeah, this is a serious pain in the rear. Thankfully, they added the "Improve" button in a response to our previous cries about it. I only recently learned, however, that not only does this implicitly approve the edit, *it awards the proposer +2 points*. If your first instinct was to *reject* the edit, this is surely not what you want!