# Valid Question Edit got rejected by "Community" first and approved next?

Tags: bug

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685657/phonegap-application-stops-unexpectedly-on-indigo-running-android-adt-20) was initially titled with two words as "Phonegap application" to which I have made an edit to make more sense out of it (the one you see now).

Although when I initially made the edit, it was rejected by the "Community". Inspite of the rejection I made an edit again and it got approved by peers as I expected.

Why did this happen?

Comment: While editing, did you get the orange popup about "Another edit has been made"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original poster submitted an edit shortly after you first submitted your suggestion. If the edit was started before you submitted your suggestion, that overrides your suggestion and that is automatically rejected by Community.

If that were not so, accepting your suggestion would roll back the changes the OP made meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the timestamps on the edits, here's a timeline of events that occurred:

```
10:24:37Z -- you submitted a suggested an edit to the post.
10:25:22Z -- Community user rejected the suggested edit.
10:27:57Z -- user submitted an edit to the post.
```

Your suggested edit was immediately rejected by the Community user when the user clicked the edit button.  This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits/78331#78331), to prevent the original author from being locked out of editing a post because of a pending suggested edit (and waiting for the two-person peer review system on Stack Overflow).